# How to play a video file in a sub folder using flowplayer?

Tags: html, flash

When using flowplayer to show videos on **Opera browser**, The videos were played fine if they were in the same folder as the page using this code.

```
<video controls width="704" height="400">
  <source src="beach.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="beach.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object id="flowplayer" width="704" height="400"
   data="FlashPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" 
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param name="movie" value="FlashPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" /> 

     <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"beach.mp4"}' />

  </object>
</video>
```

However, when I moved them to a sub folder called Videos, and used the following code:

```
<video controls width="704" height="400">
  <source src="beach.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="beach.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object id="flowplayer" width="704" height="400"
   data="FlashPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" 
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param name="movie" value="FlashPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" /> 
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"Videos/beach.mp4"}' />
  </object>
</video>
```

Nothing was played at all. So could you please show me how to pass a video path to flowplayer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should change in src

```
<video controls width="704" height="400">
  <source src="Videos/beach.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Videos/beach.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object id="flowplayer" width="704" height="400"
   data="FlashPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" 
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param name="movie" value="FlashPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" /> 
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"Videos/beach.mp4"}' />
  </object>
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's right. The source element, I thought , had no business with the flowplayer.However, it did affect.